# foreach stops after explode

Tags: php, foreach, explode

I am wonderring why foreach stops after explode, it returns the first result only:

```
$disabled_functions = ini_get('disable_functions');

print_r($disabled_functions);

$disFunctionsNoSpace = str_replace(' ', '', $disabled_functions);

// put them in an array
$disFunctions = explode(',', $disFunctionsNoSpace);

print_r($disFunctions);

/*
var_dump($disFunctions);
OUTPUT
array (size=33)
0 => string 'curl_multi_exec' (length=15)
1 => string ' parse_ini_file' (length=15)
2 => string ' symlink' (length=8)
3 => string ' shell_exec' (length=11)
4 => string ' proc_close' (length=11)
Etc
*/

$this->disFunctions = $disFunctions;

//print_r($this->disFunctions);

// get file content of the uploaded file (renamed NOT the temporary)
$cFile = file_get_contents($this->fileDestination, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);

//var_dump($cFile);

foreach($this->disFunctions as $kkeys => $vvals)
{
    echo $kkeys.' is '.$vvals.'<br />';

    if(preg_match('#'.$vvals.'#i', $cFile))
    {
        echo 'exists<br />';

        return true;
        //echo count($this->aErrors).'<br />';
        //return false;
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo $vvals.'NOT FOUND<br />';
        return false;
    }
} // end foreach
```

The result is: 0 is curl_multi_exec
curl_multi_execNOT FOUND

I am looking to get all the list of keys and vals.

Thanks for your support

Comment: Why do you have the return true and return false inside if and else statement respectively??

Comment: Because `return true` and `return false` exit the function. Once you leave the function, you also end the loop.

Comment: OHHH, sorry I forgot to remove them, it is a function

Comment: Replace `$disFunctionsNoSpace = str_replace(' ', '', $disabled_functions);` with `$disFunctionsNoSpace = str_replace(" ', '", $disabled_functions);`, and then check and let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have a `return` inside your loop.

In your `foreach` loop, you have an `if`/`else` block. Regardless of whether the `if` is satisfied, you `return` a value (`true` for the `if`, `false` for the `else`).

This `return` kills execution of your loop. It also stops any function (or method) you are in or, if you are not in a function, the current script. [From the docs:](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php)

- > **If called from within a function, the `return` statement immediately ends execution of the current function**, and returns its argument as the value of the function call. `return` also ends the execution of an [`eval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) statement or script file.
- > **If called from the global scope, then execution of the current script file is ended.** If the current script file was [`include`d](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) or [`require`d](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php), then control is passed back to the calling file. Furthermore, if the current script file was [`include`d](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php), then the value given to `return` will be returned as the value of the [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) call. If `return` is called from within the main script file, then script execution ends. If the current script file was named by the [`auto_prepend_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) or [`auto_append_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-append-file) configuration options in `php.ini`, then that script file's execution is ended.

Based on [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34523614/foreach-stops-after-explode/34523678#comment56789065_34523614) (and the fact that you're using `$this`), your loop is in a method. The `return` therefore immediately stops the loop, stops the method, and returns `true` or `false` as the case may be. It never reaches the second item in `$this->disFunctions`.